# Use or not, of lambda to define a function in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm learning racket, and I used to use `lambda` to define my functions. But I have found that it is not needed to use it (as far as I know).

I have tried these two functions in DrRacket and both returns the same result:

```
#lang racket
(define factorial
  (lambda (number)
    (cond ((not (number? number))
           (error 'factorial "number is not a number"))
          ((equal? number 0)
           1)
          (else
           (* number (factorial (- number 1)))))))

(define (factorial1 number)
    (cond ((not (number? number))
           (error 'factorial1 "number is not a number"))
          ((equal? number 0)
           1)
          (else
           (* number (factorial1 (- number 1))))))
```

The second one, `factorial1`, doesn't use lambda.

Do I need to use `lambda` when I have to declare a function?

Comment: The two forms of definition are perfectly equivalent.

Comment: the second form is a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) which effectively expands to the first form.

Comment: @user633183 Thanks to add the explanation of syntactic sugar. I'm learning a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you don't need to use `lambda`. It is perhaps more conventional and convenient to use the non-lambda version to define a function

If you use the macro stepper in DrRacket, you can see how your program is expanded. `(define (factorial1 number) etc.)` becomes the following:

```
(define-values (factorial1)
 (lambda (number)
   (if (#%app not (#%app number? number))
     (let-values () (#%app error 'factorial1 (quote "number is not a number")))
     (if (#%app equal? number (quote 0))
       (let-values () (quote 1))
       (let-values () (#%app * number (#%app factorial1 (#%app - number (quote 1)))))))))
```

Interestingly, both `define` forms, the function definition and value ones, expand to `define-values`